# What are the most optimal space-splitting data structures can be used for general incremental kNN queries?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, space-complexity

When processing data-stream, it would be required to have an incremental way to insert/delete objects. For the variations of k-nearest-neighbor queries what are most optimal minimal coverage & overlapped data structures can be used? Hierarchical data structures are preferred

Please have answers other than:
* M-Tree : Problem with overlapping though can be used with fat-factor
* R-Tree : Minimum overlapping & coverage with R* 
* B-Tree

Answer (score 0):

I think KDtree may help you.

Here's the link.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdtree

Time complexity in big O notation

Average     Worst case

Space   O(n)    O(n)

Search  O(log n)    O(n)

Insert  O(log n)    O(n)

Delete  O(log n)    O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Voronoi diagram and a point-in-location test but it's a very hard problem to solve.